# Compare vector<string> and print yes or no using c++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have two string vectors `a` and `b` with `a[0]="hello"`,`a[1]="world"`,`b[0]="heyyy"`and `b[1]="namaste"` and i have to decide whether the following `a[0] and b[0]` has anything matching and `a[1] and b[1]` has anything matching. If `a[0] and b[0]` has one or more characters matching then print `"YES"`, else print `"NO"`. Similarly if `a[1] and b[1]` has one or more characters matching then print `"YES"`, else print `"NO"`. For example from the above information, `a[0] and b[0]` have `'h' and 'e'` as matching and `a[1] and b[1]` has no character matching.  At the end, the expected output is

`"YES"
 "NO"`

Based on the above information, being a beginner in C++ i developed a C++ program which is not even partially correct. It would be great if someone solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 std::vector<string>a,b;
 a={"hello", "world"};
 b={"heyyy", "namaste"};
 const char* acstr;
 const char* bcstr;   
 acstr = a[0].c_str();
 bcstr = b[0].c_str();
 for(int i=0;i<sizeof(acstr);i++)
 {
    for(int j=0;j<sizeof(bcstr);j++)
    {
        if(acstr[i]==bcstr[j])
        {
            cout << "YES";
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }             
    }
 }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would write a function that does the comparison on two `string`s and returns a `bool`. Once that works, THEN I'll worry about looping over the vector.

Comment: For your comparison, are you looking to see if two string `a` and `b` have any equivalent substrings? (e.g. `s = "axxx"` and `b = "yyyya"` would return `true` since they both contain `a`) Or are you only checking to see if `a[i] == b[i]` for any `i` in [0, `min(a.size(), b.size())`?

Comment: why are you mixing `std::string` with `const char*` ? `std::string` can do all that `const char*` can (and more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to convert an object of the type std::string to pointer like

```
acstr = a[0].c_str();
```

Also in this loop

```
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(acstr);i++)
```

the expression `sizeof(acstr)` does not give the length of the pointed string. It gives the size of the pointer itself that depending on the used system can be equal to 4 or 8 bytes independent on the length of the pointed string.

In general the vectors can have different number of elements. So you need to use the size of the smallest vector in a loop.

To determine whether a character is present in a string you can use method `find` of the class `std::string`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v1 = { "hello", "world" };
    std::vector<std::string> v2 = { "heyyy", "namaste" };

    std::vector<std::string>::size_type n = std::min( v1.size(), v2.size() );

    for ( std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::string::size_type j = 0;
        while ( j < v1[i].size() && v2[i].find( v1[i][j] ) == std::string::npos )
        {
            ++j;
        }

        std::cout << ( j == v1[i].size() ? "NO" : "YES" ) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
YES
NO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int flag = 0;
 std::vector<string>a,b;
 a={"hello", "world"};
 b={"heyyy", "namaste"};  
 for(int k=0;k<2;k++){  //You can find and put the length of a or b, instead of using 2
     for(int i=0;i<a[k].length();i++)
     {
        for(int j=0;j<b[k].length();j++)
        {
            if(a[k][i]==b[k][j])
            {
                flag = 1;
            }            
        }
     }
    if(flag == 1){
         cout << "YES\n";
    }else{
        cout << "NO\n";
    }
    flag = 0;
 }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? `sizeof(acstr)` should be the size of a pointer, not the size of the c-style string.

Comment: Hey @JohnFilleau, You may be right because I'm from C background only. But it worked fine for me when I tested in online c++ compiler.

Comment: It's the same in C. I'd say, _especially_ with a C-background you should know how to determine the length of a string correctly. `sizeof(void*)` is usually 4 or 8, so you might be lucky, because all the strings have less than 8 characters. But it's still wrong and causes some out-of-bounds accesses.

Comment: sizeof pointer is definitely wrong. Please correct to strlen or delete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want like:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>  // do not use this header
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<string>a, b;
    a = { "hello", "world" };
    b = { "heyyy", "namaste" };
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)a.size(); i++)
    {
        bool bFound = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < min(a[i].length(), b[i].length()); j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == b[i][j])
            {
                bFound = true;
            }
        }
        cout << (bFound ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some advices:

1. You don't have to use `c_str()` to do character comparison.
2. `sizeof(const char*)` doesn't give you length of string. use `strlen(const char*)` if you want.